# Time efficiency of Bitcoin Multi-signature Vs. threshold signature

Tags: elliptic-curves, dsa, cryptocurrency, threshold-cryptography, homomorphic-signatures

I read this paper (Securing Bitcoin wallets via a new DSA/ECDSA threshold signature scheme) that illustrated that threshold signature is the best solution to avoid single point of failure

but I think multi-sig is better than threshold signature in term of time  efficiency because it is non-interactive algorithm and each party can sign separately not like threshold

I am wondering if that correct inference or not ?

Answer (score 2):

There are some possible advantages to threshold signing. First, it enables a more flexible setting where the key can be divided into $n$ parts and any subset of $t$ can be used to sign. Second, you can go from holding a single key in one place to distributing it and back without making any changes. Third, you can achieve a type of [proactive security](http://u.cs.biu.ac.il/~herzbea/Papers/proactive/cryptobytes%20paper.pdf) by generating a new resharing of the signing key at frequent intervals.

However, you are right that for the very basic usage, multi-sigs will be much simpler. (I don't think that efficiency is a huge issue here since you typically wouldn't be doing a huge number of transactions all the time. Bitcoin isn't good for many fast transactions.)